# Why can't I write a function with the same type as Box::new?

Tags: rust, dynamic-sizing

If I write a function that takes one argument of type `[f32]` (as opposed to e.g. `&[f32]`), I get an error:

```
the trait bound `[f32]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
```

The docs say this is because `[f32]` does not have a compile-time-known size. A reasonable limitation. Fair enough.

However, there is at least one function in the standard library with this type. Here's me calling it:

```
let b: Box<[f32]> = Box::new([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]);
```

How come this is allowed in the standard library and not in my code? What is the relevant difference? (There's no obvious magic in [the source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/up/src/liballoc/boxed.rs.html#225-236)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[f32]` is unsized. However, `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]` is sized... its type is `[f32; 3]`.

That's what `T` will be when compiled with the standard library code, an `[f32; 3]` sized array.

To accept a sized array yourself, you can do the same:

```
fn my_func(array: [f32; 3]) {
    // Implementation here
}

my_func([1.0, 0.0, 0.0]);
```

[Click here to see a working sample](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=99f8bf433687c971656119c916adde04&version=stable&backtrace=0) on the Playground

An `&[f32]` slice is sized too.. which is why it is allowed also.

As Lukas points out in the comments, slices are a "fat pointer" ([You can read about Dynamically Sized Types in the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html)). Slice fat pointers consist of a pointer to a piece of data and a value representing how big that data is.

Comment: I gave an explicit type for `b`. Does that not determine the type at which Box is instantiated?

Comment: @apt1002 That type constraint causes `Box<[f32; 3]>` to coerce to `Box<[f32]>`.  You can prove this by trying to use an obviously incorrect type: `let b: () = Box::new([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]);` will produce an error telling you that the right-hand side is `Box<[{float}; 3]>` (because float literals aren't of any specific float type at this point).

Comment: *Its size is that of a reference* -> no, it's a fat pointer, so the size is twice the size of a pointer.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I did actually mean that but failed to convey it. I will rephrase now that I am home.