# How does Rust handle converting &SizedType to &UnsizedType?

Tags: rust

```rust
struct MaybeSized<T: ?Sized> {
    v: T,
}

fn main() {
    let sized = MaybeSized {
        v: "sized".to_string(),
    };

    use std::fmt::Display;

    {
        // what exactly happens here?
        let ref1: &MaybeSized<Display> = &sized;
    }
    {
        // why this fails to compile?
        let ref2: &MaybeSized<str> = &sized;
    }
}
```

`MaybeSize<String>` is a sized type; what is on the stack and heap when `ref1 : &MaybeSized<Display>`) is created? Why this "magic" doesn't work for another unsized type like `MaybeSized<str>`?

Comment: I suppose you meant
```rust
let ref2: &MaybeSized<str> = &sized;
```
`ref` is a reserved keyword. `str` won't work either, though.

Comment: See also [How does the mechanism behind the creation of boxed traits work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52288980/155423)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion from `&MaybeSized<String>` to `&MaybeSized<dyn Display>` is called an [unsized coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions). Concrete types can be coerced into trait objects for the traits they implement, and this coercion extends to a generic struct under certain conditions:

> `Foo<..., T, ...>` to `Foo<..., U, ...>`, when:
>
> - `Foo` is a struct.
> - `T` implements `Unsize<U>`.
> - The last field of `Foo` has a type involving `T`.
> - If that field has type `Bar<T>`, then `Bar<T>` implements `Unsized<Bar<U>>`.
> - `T` is not part of the type of any other fields.

(For the full details follow the link to the language reference above.)

The variable `sized` is stored on the stack, but the data of the `String` is allocated on the heap. The reference `ref1` is stored on the stack as a *fat pointer* – a pointer to `sized` together with a pointer to the virtual method table for `String as dyn Display` to allow dynamically calling the right methods if necessary.

This doesn't work for `MaybeSized<str>` because there is no unsized coercion that converts to `str`. You can convert and `&String` to a `&str` using a *deref coercion*, but that's not what we need here – unsizing a sized type requires an unsized coercion. The unsized type `MaybeSized<str>` consists of the *actual string data*, while `MaybeSized<String>` consists of a length, a capacity and a pointer to the heap, so there is no way to make the memory layouts match.

There are other cases that work, though, e.g.

```
let a = MaybeSized { v: [65u8, 66, 67]};
let b: &MaybeSized<[u8]> = &a;
```

works fine, since there is an unsized coercion from `[u8; 3]` to `[u8]`. With unsafe code you can convert this to `&MaybeSized<str>` if you really want to:

```
let c: &MaybeSized<str> = unsafe { &*(b as *const _ as *const _) };
```

I can't think of a safe way of creating a `&MaybeSized<str>`.

([Code on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c7c80d1ffed5fa59865083f530a34d0))