# Can I safely cast Box<dyn Any + Send> to Box<dyn Any>?

Tags: rust, unsafe

`Send` is a marker trait, and does not have any impact on memory layout. That said, the mechanics of the `Any` type remain slightly mysterious to me.

Is the following code sound and does it do what I want: the cast type will always downcast correctly to the original concrete type:

```rust
let what_i_have: Box<dyn Any + Send> = Box::new(69);
let ptr = Box::into_raw(what_i_have);
let what_i_want: Box<dyn Any> = unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr as *mut dyn Any) };
```

I've played around with this, and it "seems to work fine". Is it?

As a bonus question, can I do this without the `unsafe` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this safely by assigning the value:

```
use std::any::Any;

fn main() {
    let what_i_have: Box<dyn Any + Send> = Box::new(69);
    let what_i_want: Box<dyn Any> = what_i_have;
}
```

See also:

- [How does the mechanism behind the creation of boxed traits work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52288980/155423)

Comment: great, thanks, for some reason I assumed the casting would have to happen "inside" the box?

Comment: @cmyr I think [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html) is the magic trick that allows such coercions to work. ([`Box<dyn Any + Send>` implements `CoerceUnsized<Box<dyn Any>>`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=facb415279ab73a6a08f82ef48d846b0).)

Comment: Yep. I’ve been trying to find reasonable links that discuss that trait to add to the “see also”