# How to cast Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + Send + Sync>> to Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + Sync>> in rust?

Tags: rust, casting, trait-objects

I'm failing to cast `dyn SomeTrait + Send + Sync` to `dyn SomeTrait + Sync`.

More specifically, I am trying to cast `&Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + Send + Sync>>` to `&Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + Sync>>`.

I tried simply reassining [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59953080/14385360) as well as using `as` but neither approach worked.

How can I accomplish what I want?

The error message is

```
expected trait `ToSql + Sync`, found trait `ToSql + Send + Sync`
```

Edit: Also, it would be nice to know, why this doesn't just work, since the conversion should be possible because we know that each `dyn SomeTrait + Send + Sync>` satisfies `SomeTrait + Sync`

Comment: Do you really want to convert `&Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + Send + Sync>>` to `&Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + Sync>>` (emphasis on the reference) or just `Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + Send + Sync>>` to `Vec<Box<dyn SomeTrait + Sync>>`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I really need the Vec to be a reference

Comment: And are you sure a slice (`&[Box<dyn SomeTrait + Send + Sync>]` to `&[Box<dyn SomeTrait + Sync>]`) won't do?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Only if I can then convert to `&[&(dyn SomeTrait + Sync)]`, which I didn't manage to do without a vec.

Comment: You can do that only with unsafe code. But if you can't do that with a `Vec`, why does `Vec` help you?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I can do so safely with a Vec: `let foo = ref_to_vec.iter().map(|i| i.as_ref()).collect::<Vec<_>>();` and then `foo.as_slice()`

Comment: Ah yes, by allocating. You can definitely do that with a slice too.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman would you mind posting an answer showing the conversion from `&[Box<dyn SomeTrait + Send + Sync>]` to `&[Box<dyn SomeTrait + Sync>]`? Or is it a simple cast?

Comment: I'm working on a (long) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the hard things. If you want an easy solution, jump to the end of the answer (the last section).

---

So: the fact is, it indeed could work. Why doesn't it? Well, apparently there are some problems, but the main problem is probably that nobody worked on that. [There is a thread in internals.rust-lang.org discussing that](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/trait-objects-auto-trait-subtyping/15630).

First thing to do, we need to understand the difference between *coercion* and *subtyping*.

*Coercing* type `T` to `U` means that when you have something of type `T` and you want to convert it to type `U` the compiler can do that for you automagically. You just need to declare that you want type `U` and the compiler will do its magic and give it for you. For example, a reference to an array (`&[T; N]`) it can be coerced to a reference to slice (`&[T]`). When you have a reference to an array and you pass it to something (e.g. a function) that expects a reference to a slice, the compiler automatically inserts code to convert the pointer to the array (what a reference to array is in assembly code) to a pointer + size (what a reference to slice is in assembly code).

Generally, every conversion can be a coercion. It just needs to be built into the language, and the compiler has to know how to insert code to do it. However, Rust has the principle that *expensive things should be explicit*, and so, coercions (that are implicit) need to be cheap.

The important thing for us to understand about coercions is that *they're not transitive*. That is, if type `T` can be coerced to `U`, that doesn't mean that `G<T>` can be coerced to `G<U>`. Or, in simpler words, the fact that `&[T; N]` can be coerced to `&[T]` doesn't mean that we can also coerce `Vec<&[T; N]>` to `Vec<&[T]>`. The reason is simple: since coercion needs to actually insert code to perform the conversion, we don't know how to generate the code for the wrapper type. The fact that we know to convert `&[T; N]` to `&[T]` (by simply attaching the size) doesn't mean we know to convert a vector of `&[T; N]`s to a vector of `&[T]`s, a thing that requires allocating and copying (since the size of `&[T]` is double the size of `&[T; N]`).

A *subtyping relationship* is a completely different thing. If a type `T` is a subtype of `U`, that means that *any `T` is also `U`*. The classic example is base classes in OOP languages. A instance of `Derived` is also an instance of `Base`. This does mean that, like with coercions, a pointer to `Derived` can be converted to a pointer to `Base`, but unlike with coercions, *this doesn't require inserting any conversion code*.

The only subtypings in Rust as of time of writing are lifetime relationships. For example, `'static` is a subtype of any lifetime, and that means that `&'static T` is a subtype of any `&'a T`. This is why you can give `&'static T` where `&'a T` is expected.

Because no code to convert is required, subtyping *is* transitive. You can convert `Vec<&'static T>` to `Vec<&'a T>`. The exception to that is variance, which I won't talk about now.

---

Now to the important point: the conversion from `dyn Trait + Send + Sync` to `dyn Trait + Sync` (in other words, the removal of additional auto-trait bounds from `dyn Trait`) is a coercion and not subtyping. This is why you cannot convert `&Vec<Box<dyn Trait + Send + Sync>>` to `&Vec<Box<dyn Trait + Sync>>` - the conversion is not transitive.

There is no reason why it couldn't be subtyping - no code is required for the conversion, other than that, as I already said, nobody worked on that.

---

But can we still do that?

Using unsafe code, yes; but also no.

The conversion from `&Vec<Box<dyn Trait + Send + Sync>>` to `&Vec<Box<dyn Trait + Sync>>` is not allowed, period. Even assuming `Box<dyn Trait + Send + Sync>` and `Box<dyn Trait + Sync>` have the same layout, two `Vec`s containing them is not guaranteed to have the same layout too. So what you asked for cannot be done.

But how about something similar: converting from `Vec<Box<dyn Trait + Send + Sync>>` to `Vec<Box<dyn Trait + Sync>>` (no reference). Or similarly, `&[Box<dyn Trait + Send + Sync>]` to `&[Box<dyn Trait + Sync>]`. Or even `&Vec<Box<dyn Trait + Send + Sync>>` to `&[&(dyn Trait + Send + Sync)]`?

We can use [`Vec::from_raw_parts()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts) (or [`std::slice::from_raw_parts()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html)) to build the `Vec` (or the slice) without relying on its layout specifics. But we still need that a pointer to `dyn Trait + AutoTrait` will have the same layout as a pointer to `dyn Trait`. Does this hold?

Well, currently, yes; and I believe it will also hold in the future. But it is not documented anywhere, so I would not rely on that.

---

However, from your comments, it looks like all you want is to get a slice `&[&(dyn SomeTrait + Sync)]` and you do not even care if you allocate or not. Well, this can be done very easily:

```rust
let v2: Vec<&(dyn SomeTrait + Sync)> = v.iter().map(|item| &**item as _).collect();
let v2: &[&(dyn SomeTrait + Sync)] = v2.as_slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this:

```rust
let my_new_vec: Vec<_> = my_old_vec
          .into_iter()
          .map(|x|->Box<dyn SomeTrait + Sync>{x})
          .collect();
```

There is a chance that compiler would be able to optimize loop away.

Comment: This doesn't do what requested: this converts `Vec`, not `&Vec`. You can use `iter()` + `cloned()`, but this will definitely not be optimized away.

Comment: Also, what kind of syntax is this? I've never seen `->` in rust before

Comment: @Einliterflasche, You can find `->` in any beginning tutorial on Rust functions, for instance:`fn get_number() -> u8 {10}`.  In the answer above, it's being used as part of the basic syntax of a closure.