# Why can't I create a trait object with let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = value.into()?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, trait-objects

```
use std::sync::Arc;

trait Trait {}
struct TraitImpl {}
impl Trait for TraitImpl {}

fn main() {
    let value = TraitImpl {};
    let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = Arc::new(value);    // compiles
    let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = value.into();       // doesn't compile
}
```

Result

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::sync::Arc<dyn Trait>: std::convert::From<TraitImpl>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:35
   |
10 |     let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = value.into();       // doesn't compile
   |                                   ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<TraitImpl>` is not implemented for `std::sync::Arc<dyn Trait>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::sync::Arc<T> as std::convert::From<T>>
             <std::sync::Arc<T> as std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<T>>>
             <std::sync::Arc<[T]> as std::convert::From<&[T]>>
             <std::sync::Arc<[T]> as std::convert::From<std::vec::Vec<T>>>
           and 8 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<std::sync::Arc<dyn Trait>>` for `TraitImpl`
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6bf94209b77122a0336e554ff30c7411))

Why does `Arc::new(value)` compile but not `value.into()`? I don't understand why [`Arc<T>::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.new) is satisfied while [`From<T>::from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#impl-From%3CT%3E) isn't.

```
impl<T> Arc<T> {
    pub fn new(data: T) -> Arc<T>
}
```

```
impl<T> From<T> for Arc<T> {
    fn from(t: T) -> Arc<T>
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference in your two lines. The first one:

```
let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = Arc::new(value);
```

The pattern is not important for the resolution of `Arc::new()`, since it is defined as you noted:

```
impl<T> Arc<T> {
    pub fn new(data: T) -> Arc<T>
}
```

So the type `T` is deduced from the type of `value` that is `TraitImpl`, and an `Arc<TraitImpl>` is created.
Then this type is implicitly [unsized-coerced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52288980/3650362) to that `Arc<dyn Trait>` and all compiles fine.

---

But the second line is tricker:

```
let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = value.into();
```

Since there is not an `into` function in `TraitImpl` the compiler searches any trait in scope and finds `Into<T>::into()`, that is defined as:

```
pub trait Into<T> {
    fn into(self) -> T;
}
```

Now the compiler wonders what type would that `T` be. Since it is the return of the function, it guesses that `T` is `Arc<dyn Trait>`. Now the only interesting implementation of `Into` is in terms of `From`:

```
impl<X, T> Into<T> for X where
    T: From<X>
```

Here `X` is `TraitImpl` and `T` is `Arc<dyn Trait>`. If you look at the impls of  `Arc` for `From`, it includes a lot of them, but none that applies. This is the most similar:

```
impl<T> From<T> for Arc<T>
```

Then, the compiler shows a few of the failing candidates and emits an error.

---

The *TL;DR;* is that you actually want to do two conversions: from `TraitImpl` to `Arc<TraitImpl>` and then from  `Arc<TraitImpl>` to `Arc<dyn Trait>`. But you cannot do both in a single coertion, the compiler must have the intermediate type spelled out somehow.

Answer (score 2):

For all generic Rust code there is an implicit `Sized` bound on any `T`. This:

```rust
fn func<T>(t: &T) {}
```

Is actually this:

```rust
fn func<T: Sized>(t: &T) {}
```

Which may not always be what you want so it's the only trait you have to explicitly opt-out of like so:

```rust
fn func<T: ?Sized>(t: &T) {}
```

So in your case:

```rust
impl<T> From<T> for Arc<T> {
    fn from(t: T) -> Arc<T>
}
```

Is actually:

```rust
impl<T: Sized> From<T> for Arc<T> {
    fn from(t: T) -> Arc<T>
}
```

Which is why you can't `some_value.into()` an `Arc<dyn Anything>` since all trait objects are unsized.

As to why this restriction exists in the first place we can determine that by looking at the definition of `From<T>`:

```rust
pub trait From<T> {
    fn from(T) -> Self;
}
```

`from(T)` means it has to take some `T` and put it in the function's call stack, which means `T` has to have a known size at compile-time and must therefore be `Sized`.

**Update**

So this also applies to `Arc::new(T)` since that function is defined in an impl block like so:

```
impl<T> for Arc<T> {
    fn new(T) -> Arc<T> {
        ...
    }
}
```

And when you call `Arc::new(TraitImpl);` you are indeed calling it with a `Sized` type since `TraitImpl`'s size is known at compile-time but then *an unsized coercion* is triggered by the `let` variable binding since you ask Rust to treat `Arc<TraitImpl>` as if it was an `Arc<dyn Trait>`.

This unsized coercion isn't triggered when you call `value.into()` since `From<T>` only takes `Sized` types.

However, if you are determined to use `From<T>` you can do so like this:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

trait Trait {}
struct TraitImpl {}
impl Trait for TraitImpl {}

fn main() {
    let value = TraitImpl {};
    let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = Arc::new(value); // compiles
    let value = TraitImpl {};
    let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = <Arc<TraitImpl>>::from(value); // also compiles
}
```

In this example you make it clear you're going from a sized type to another sized type, i.e. `TraitImpl` to `Arc<TraitImpl>`, before you trigger the unsized coercion `Arc<TraitImpl>` to `Arc<dyn Trait>`.

Here are other variations:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

trait Trait {}
struct TraitImpl {}
impl Trait for TraitImpl {}

fn main() {
    let value = TraitImpl {};
    let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = Arc::new(value); // compiles

    let value = TraitImpl {};
    let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = <Arc<TraitImpl>>::from(value); // compiles

    let value = TraitImpl {};
    let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = Arc::from(value); // compiles, can infer Arc<TraitImpl> here

    let value = TraitImpl {};
    let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = Into::<Arc<TraitImpl>>::into(value); // compiles

    let value = TraitImpl {};
    let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = Into::<Arc<_>>::into(value); // compiles, can infer Arc<TraitImpl> here

    let value = TraitImpl {};
    let _: Arc<dyn Trait> = Into::into(value); // doesn't compile, infers Arc<dyn Trait> here
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that apply to `impl<T> Arc<T>` too?

Comment: @JohnKugelman it does not apply to Arc<T>, I've updated my answer to explain why, but here's also a link to [Arc's source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/sync.rs.html#196-199) if you wanna see for yourself.

Comment: Hm. `struct Arc` has `T: ?Sized`, but the `impl<T>` block doesn't. Doesn't that mean `impl<T>`  is `impl<T: Sized>`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman is right, `fn new` is defined in an `impl<T> Arc<T>` block with no `?Sized` bound. The reason it works is because `Arc::new(value)` returns an `Arc<TraitImpl>` which can be coerced to `Arc<dyn Trait>`. `value.into()` uses type inference to determine what `.into()` must return and gets confused because there is no `impl From<TraitImpl> for Arc<dyn Trait>`.

Comment: Right, when you call `Arc::new(TraitImpl);` at the time of that call `TraitImpl` is indeed `Sized` but then is coerced to the unsized type `Arc<dyn Trait>` in the `let` variable binding.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I've updated my answer to be more thorough and also mention unsized coercions, I hope it's now satisfactory.

Comment: What is an unsized coercion?

Comment: @JohnKugelman it's when you coerce / cast a sized type to an unsized type, like in the case of coercing / casting `Arc<TraitImpl>` to `Arc<dyn Trait>`.

Comment: `Arc::from(value)` also works with no explicit `TraitImpl`. I believe this is because mentioning `Arc` hints to the compiler that it should infer the type parameter *here* and not simply copy it from the left hand side of the `=`. Elaborating a little, `Into::<Arc<_>>::into(value)` works, but `Into::<_>::into(value)` does not.