# Is it true that for all types `T`, `U` if `T` is coerced to `U` then `&T` is coerced to `&U`?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, type-coercion

It's [well documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions) that `[T; n]` can coerce to `[T]`. The following code is also [well-formed](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6108b3df0dcde5d2e5e0ff603a2b7cef):

```
fn test(){
    let _a: &[i32] = &[1, 2, 3];
}
```

Here we have that `&[T; n]` is coerced to `&[T]`.

Is it true that for all types `T`, `U` if `T` is coerced to `U` then `&T` is coerced to `&U`?

It's not documented in the reference (at least explicitly).

Comment: @PeterHall That's true and is well-docuemeted. The question is what rule governs the `&[T; n]` to `&[T]`?

Comment: This is actually kind of documented on the page you linked – `CoerceUnsized<&U> for &T` is implemented for `T: Unsize<U>`, which implies that the coercion in your example exists.

Comment: It may be slightly clearer in the Nomicon: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html

Comment: And from the same page: `&T` or `&mut T` to `&U` if `T` implements `Deref<Target = U>`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks. If you posted it as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: See also [How does the mechanism behind the creation of boxed traits work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52288980/155423)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because adding one more layer of `&` causes it to fail:

```
fn oops() {
    let a: &[i32; 3] = &[1, 2, 3];
    let _b: &&[i32] = &a;
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:8:23
  |
8 |     let _b: &&[i32] = &a;
  |             -------   ^^ expected slice `[i32]`, found array `[i32; 3]`
  |             |
  |             expected due to this
  |
  = note: expected reference `&&[i32]`
             found reference `&&[i32; 3]`
```

Further, it is not the case that `[T; n]` *coerces to* `[T]` in the same sense that `&[T; n]` *coerces to* `&[T]`. The documentation you linked describes the two traits related to unsized coercions: `Unsize` and `CoerceUnsized`. `[T; n]` implements `Unsize<[T]>`, and *therefore* `&[T; n]` implements `CoerceUnsized<&[T]>`; this is essentially the same thing, and your code effectively demonstrates both. It would not be possible to write a function that coerces `[T; n]` to `[T]` *without* using references (or pointers of some sort) because unsizing coercions only take place behind some kind of pointer.

Comment: Essentially, an unsized coercion always converts some kind of _pointer_ into a _fat pointer_. The documentation is indeed somewhat confusingly worded and could be imporved.