# Can't box unsized type with fully qualified syntax

Tags: rust

I tried boxing a closure using the fully qualified syntax:

```rust
let x = Box::<SomeType>::new(some_value);
```

and had expected this to work in the exact same way as:

```rust
let x: Box<SomeType> = Box::new(some_value);
```

i.e.: compile.

Instead, I have gotten a compiler error saying that the method `new` cannot be called on `Box` with unsized type parameter:

```rust
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `new` found for struct `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::FnMut() -> i32>` in the current scope
   --> src/bin/observable_test/mod.rs:57:40
    |
57  |     let boxed = Box::<dyn FnMut() -> i32>::new(|| 0);
    |                                           ^^^ function or associated item not found in `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::FnMut() -> i32>`
    | 
   ::: /mnt/data/william stanley/applications/rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:151:1
    |
151 | pub trait FnMut<Args>: FnOnce<Args> {
    | ----------------------------------- doesn't satisfy `dyn std::ops::FnMut() -> i32: std::marker::Sized`
    |
    = note: the method `new` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `dyn std::ops::FnMut() -> i32: std::marker::Sized`
```

I think that this might be caused by the `impl` of `Box`'s methods being declared as

```rust
impl<T> Box<T> {
    ...
}
```

and therefore implicitly require the type parameter to be `Sized`, but if that is the case, why is it declared in this way, and why does the call work when it isn't qualified?

Comment: This seems like a likely duplicate of [How does the mechanism behind the creation of boxed traits work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288980/how-does-the-mechanism-behind-the-creation-of-boxed-traits-work) Since you already self-answered (and the answer is good), it might be useful to migrate your answer to the other question, so people who end up there will be able to find it more easily. However if you don't want to do that I don't think there is anything wrong with leaving it here.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't seen that question. Since your and Rodrigo's answers on that question are better formulated and contain official terminology, I see no value in migrating my answer there and will just mark the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This indeed does happen because of the way the `Box`'s `impl` is declared, but if you think about it, it does make sense: The `new` method takes a value that is on the stack, and therefore it must be `Sized`.

> why does the call work when it isn't qualified?

This often (but not always) works, because the type you are supplying to the `new` function is actually not unsized - it is only widened to an unsized type once it is assigned to a variable with more general type.

Let's reuse the example you used, and find out why the second version you posted works:

```rust
let boxed: Box<dyn FnMut() -> i32> = Box::new(|| 0);
```

The rust reference [states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#closure-types):

> A closure expression produces a closure value with a unique, anonymous type that cannot be written out. A closure type is approximately equivalent to a struct which contains the captured variables.

This means that the type of closure passed to `new` is not actually `dyn FnMut() -> i32`, but rather a unique type of the one specific closure, which can not be written out in any way, and therefore has to be inferred.

The reference also later [notes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#other-traits):

> All closure types implement `Sized`.

So indeed, the type was sized all along, it's just that the later assignment to a variable of type `dyn FnMut() -> i32` has widened the original closure type to a more general, unsized one.