# Error when passing Rc<dyn Trait> as a function argument

Tags: rust

I'm facing some strange behavior when passing an `Rc<dyn Trait>` as a function argument. The following code demonstrates the problem.

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Trait {}

struct Struct {}

impl Trait for Struct {}

fn function(_t: Rc<dyn Trait>) {}

fn main() {
    let n = Rc::new(Struct {});

    // ok
    let r = Rc::clone(&n);
    function(r);

    // error, why?
    // function(Rc::clone(&n));
}
```

If I store the `Rc` in a temporary variable, everything works fine. But if I try to call `Rc::clone` directly within the function call, I get the following error.

```
   |
19 |     function(Rc::clone(&n));
   |                        ^^ expected trait object `dyn Trait`, found struct `Struct`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&std::rc::Rc<dyn Trait>`
              found reference `&std::rc::Rc<Struct>`
```

`Struct` implements `Trait`. Why do I get this error?

Comment: Why not `n.clone()`?

Comment: I'm new to the language, but the documentation suggests that when dealing with Rc, Rc::clone is the preferred syntax to signal that one is dealing with an Rc and not a Copy. Interestingly, n.clone() works...

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a turbofish version that does work, but I'm having no luck. I don't think `Rc::clone` can figure out what's going on due to conflicting definitions for the return type vs. the given value, while `n.clone()` only has to deal with the return type.

Comment: I tried that as well, albeit with no luck. :-)

Comment: I would have thought that `Rc::clone::<Rc<Struct>>(&n)` would do it, but that just made things worse. Maybe someone who knows Rust better can weigh in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is basically just a wrinkle in the type inference rules. In order to call `Rc::clone(&n)`, the compiler has to know what the type parameter of `Rc` is.

```
let r = Rc::clone(&n);
function(r);
```

At the first line, the compiler sees that `Rc::clone` is called with an argument of type `&Rc<Struct>`. It can freely pick a type for `r`, so it infers that the function being called should be `Rc::<Struct>::clone` and `r` is also `Rc<Struct>`. Moving to the next line, calling `function(r)` just [coerces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288980/how-does-the-mechanism-behind-the-creation-of-boxed-traits-work) `r` to `Rc<dyn Trait>`.

```
function(Rc::clone(&n));
```

Here the compiler again has to pick a type parameter for `Rc`, but it doesn't have total freedom: it has to pick something that can be passed to `function`. So it assumes the type parameter is `dyn Trait`, since `Rc<dyn Trait>` is what `function` expects.

However, you cannot call `Rc::<dyn Trait>::clone(&n)`, because while `Rc<Struct>` can be coerced to `Rc<dyn Trait>`, [coercions are not transitive through referencing](/q/63452165/3650362) (you can't coerce a `&Rc<Struct>` to `&Rc<dyn Trait>`). So coercion cannot take place inside the `Rc::clone(...)` call.

You can make the one-line version compile by specifying the type argument as `Struct` using a turbofish:

```
function(Rc::<Struct>::clone(&n));
```

or by hinting to the compiler that it should not infer the type from its position as the argument of `function`, by adding an explicit cast:

```
function(Rc::clone(&n) as _);
```

`n.clone()` also works because the [method resolution procedure for `.`](/q/28519997/3650362) leaves no room for doubt about the type parameter: it will always find `Rc::<Struct>::clone` because auto-dereferencing only looks at the receiver type (the type of `n`) and does not care about the expression's context.

### Related

- [How does the mechanism behind the creation of boxed traits work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52288980/3650362)