# Calling static method on type alias

Tags: types, rust, closures, type-alias, trait-objects

While using boxed closures I ran into the following issue:

```rust
type Test = Rc<dyn Fn() -> i64>;

fn test_bad() -> Test {
    Test::new(|| 42)
}

fn test_good() -> Test {
    Rc::new(|| 42)
}
```

In the first case, I'm using the type alias to refer to the `new` method, whereas I'm using `Rc` directly in the second case.

In the first case, the compiler complains:

```
    |       Test::new(|| 42)
    |             ^^^ function or associated item not found in `Rc<(dyn Fn() -> i64 + 'static)>`
    |
    = note: the method `new` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `dyn Fn() -> i64: Sized`
```

But the second case works just fine. Can somebody please explain the difference? Is there any way to refer to `new` through the type alias or do I need to wrap it myself?

Comment: [Error when passing Rc<dyn Trait> as a function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63893847/3650362) might also be found helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `test_good`, by calling `Rc::new` on `|| 42`, you **don't** create an `Rc<dyn Fn() -> i64>`, but an `Rc<ClosureType>`, where `ClosureType` is the [unique type of the closure provided](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html), and it **is** sized. Then, since the `Rc<ClosureType>` is returned in a function that returns `Rc<dyn Fn() -> i64>`, it implicitly casts it to a trait object.

`test_bad` fails because instead of going from constructing an `Rc` of a sized closure then casting it to an `Rc` of an unsized trait object, it tries to directly construct an `Rc` of an unsized trait object, which fails since all arguments to functions must be sized.

I don't think there's a direct way to refer to `new` through the type alias, although you could very easily make your own:

```rust
fn new_test(func: impl 'static + Fn() -> i64) -> Test {
    Rc::new(func)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A generic type alias works, but a concrete one fails:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

type MyGenericRc<T> = Rc<T>;

// works
fn construct_with_generic_alias() -> MyGenericRc<dyn Fn() -> i64> {
    MyGenericRc::new(|| 42)
}

type MyConcreteRc = Rc<dyn Fn() -> i64>;

// fails
fn construct_with_concrete_alias() -> MyConcreteRc {
    MyConcreteRc::new(|| 42)
}
```

When you call `MyGenericRc::new(<closure>)` the compiler picks `Rc::<closure type>::new(<closure>)` as the concrete function implementation to use, which works since `Rc::new` requires a `Sized` argument and every anonymous closure type is `Sized`. However, after that function is called the compiler performs an *unsizing coercion* to transform the returned `Rc<anonymous closure type>` into an `Rc<dyn Fn() -> i64>`.

When you call `MyConcreteRc::new(<closure>)` you don't let the compiler decide which `Rc::new` implementation to use, you tell it that it must use `Rc::<dyn Fn() -> i64>::new` but it's impossible to satisfy that implementation's type requirements because `new` expects a `Sized` argument but `dyn Fn() -> i64` is `!Sized`, hence the compile error message you are seeing.