# Cloning an Rc pointer over a trait object in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits, smart-pointers, trait-objects

I am learning Rust and don't understand why the following doesnt work. I gather we are unable to clone an Rc pointer over a trait object? How am I to pass such a reference to an function defined only by a trait, as attempted in `some_function`?

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait SomeTrait {}
struct SomeThing {}
impl SomeTrait for SomeThing {}

fn some_function(s: Rc<dyn SomeTrait>) {}
fn another_function(s: &Rc<dyn SomeTrait>) {}

fn main() {
    let s = Rc::new(SomeThing{});

    // This doesnt work
    some_function(Rc::clone(&s));

    // I could do this
    some_function(s);

    // But then I could not do this
    some_function(s);
    
    // For that matter, neither can I do this
    another_function(&s);
}
```

Comment: Hello, see at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893847/error-when-passing-rcdyn-trait-as-a-function-argument

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the error messages of the compiler you will see this:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   |
14 |     some_function(Rc::clone(&s));
   |                             ^^ expected trait object `dyn SomeTrait`, found struct `SomeThing`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&Rc<dyn SomeTrait>`
              found reference `&Rc<SomeThing>`
```

That means the compiler mis-infers the type of `s` to `Rc<SomeThing>` instead of the `Rc<dyn SomeTrait>` you were looking for, which can be confirmed by the usual trick of providing a blatantly incorrect type to `let s`:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:17
   |
11 |     let s: () = Rc::new(SomeThing{});
   |            --   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found struct `Rc`
   |            |
   |            expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                 found struct `Rc<SomeThing>`
```

Since Rust wrappers are [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), an `Rc<SomeThing>` and an `Rc<dyn SomeTrait>` are *completely incompatible values*, there is no way to just use one for the other.

The solution is to simply explicitely type `s` correctly:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait SomeTrait {}
struct SomeThing {}
impl SomeTrait for SomeThing {}

fn some_function(s: Rc<dyn SomeTrait>) {}
fn another_function(s: &Rc<dyn SomeTrait>) {}

fn main() {
    let s: Rc<dyn SomeTrait> = Rc::new(SomeThing{});

    // This doesnt work
    some_function(Rc::clone(&s));
    
    // For that matter, neither can I do this
    another_function(&s);
}
```

Obviously the two calls in the middle can't work, as the first one will *move* the local `Rc`, which the second one (and the final call) still want.

Comment: Worth noting: You _can_ convert an `Rc<SomeThing>` to `Rc<dyn SomeTrait>`, but it requires an explicit cast. `some_function(Rc::clone(&s) as Rc<dyn SomeTrait>);` will compile and work. This is due to the currently unstable `CoerceUnsized` trait.