# Cannot implement EventHandler pattern in Rust

Tags: rust, tui

I am building a TUI application in Rust and I wish to *broadcast* keypress events for different parts of the application to listen to. Initially, I create a struct that handles the events:

```rs
use std::rc::Rc;
use crate::global::cursor::CursorAction;
use crate::global::state::State;

pub trait Observer {
    fn on_keypress(&mut self, cursor_action: &CursorAction, old_state: &State);
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct EventHandler {
    listeners: Vec<Rc<dyn Observer>>
}

impl EventHandler {
    pub fn register(&mut self, observer: Rc<dyn Observer>) {
        self.listeners.push(observer);
    }

    pub fn notify(&mut self, cursor_action: &CursorAction, old_state: &State) {
        for listener in &mut self.listeners {
            listener.on_keypress(cursor_action, old_state);
        }
    }
}
```

And to register this state, I do this in the `src/lib.rs` file:

```rs
use std::error::Error;
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::rc::Rc;
use crate::event_handler::{EventHandler, Observer};

use crate::global::state::State;

mod terminal;
mod global;
mod domain;
mod event_handler;

pub fn start() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut event_handler = EventHandler::default();
    let mut state: Rc<dyn Observer> = Rc::new(State::default());
    event_handler.register(Rc::clone(&state));
    init(&mut state);

    let mut terminal = terminal::setup_terminal()?;
    terminal::run(&mut terminal, &mut state, event_handler)?;
    terminal::restore_terminal(&mut terminal)?;
    Ok(())
}

fn init(state: &mut Rc<State>) {
    let raw_files = domain::retrieve_files();
    state.set_files(raw_files);
}
```

However, I get an error:

```
    init(&mut state);
    ---- ^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&mut Rc<State>`, found `&mut Rc<dyn Observer>`
```

When I have `impl Observer for State` defined. I am failing to implement this pattern in Rust and believe that it is quite difficult to do it. How do I make this implementation work? Is there any alternate approach to using this pattern?

Comment: You should not try to remove the concrete type from the `state` variable but instead cast the `Rc::clone()` when passing it to `register` as you can see in this question: [Error when passing Rc<dyn Trait> as a function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893847/error-when-passing-rcdyn-trait-as-a-function-argument)

Comment: It's a bit weird to pass around `&mut Rc` the only methods that deal with it (`get_mut` and `make_mut`) seem counter to your intentions, you should probably use interior mutability instead. i.e. `Rc<RefCell<State>` and `Rc<RefCell<dyn Observer>>` instead of the mutable references.

Comment: Why do you even use `Rc` in the first place? Why not a `Box`?

Answer (score 0):

Even assuming `Observer` trait is implemented for `State` somewhere, Rust doesn't have downcasting from `Rc<dyn Observer>` to `Rc<State>`.

Your first culprit is this line:

```rust
let mut state: Rc<dyn Observer> = Rc::new(State::default());
```

what creates polymorphic `state` variable, but without runtime information about original type.

But as others mention in comments, your use of `&mut Rc<>` is wrong - it makes *reference counting pointer* mutable, not the instance of `State`.

Now, how I see it (I'm betting w/o test as you don't provide enough code):

- Your `init()` doesn't need `&mut Rc<State>` but at most `&mut State` (btw. why not do this in constructor?)
- `let mut state = Rc::new(RefCell::new(State::default()));`
- Call `init(&**state)`

If you provide some working example I'd refactor it to what I believe be satisfactory code w/less complications.